# Python scipy fsolve to solve a large number of nonlinear equations

Tags: python, nonlinear-functions

I want to solve a system of 6 nonlinear equations using Python. I found that I can use `scipy`'s `fsolve` pretty easily to solve a system of 3 nonlinear equations. However, when I expand this to a larger system, I find that the solution does not solve the system of equations. Is there something I can correct that will allow for the solution of 6 nonlinear equations?

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def system(z):
   #arbitrary system of 3 nonlinear equations
   x1 = z[0]
   x2 = z[1]
   x3 = z[2]

   F = np.empty((3))
   F[0] = 20* x1 + x2**2
   F[1] = x2 - x1
   F[2] = x3 + 5 - x1*x2

   return F

def system2(z):
   #arbitrary system of 6 nonlinear equations
   x1 = z[0]
   x2 = z[1]
   x3 = z[2]
   x4 = z[3]
   x5 = z[4]
   x6 = z[5]

   F = np.empty((6))
   F[0] = 20* x1 + x2**2
   F[1] = x2 - x1
   F[2] = x3 + 5 - x1*x2
   F[3] = x3 + x2
   F[4] = x5 + x4**2
   F[5] = x6**2 + x1 - 20

   return F

uInitial = np.array([1,1,1])
u = fsolve(system,uInitial)
print('Solution: ',u)
print('Solution check: ',system(u),'\n') #yields zeros as expected

vInitial = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
v = fsolve(system2,vInitial)
print('Solution: ',v)
print('Solution check: ',system2(v)) #unexpectedly does not yield zeros. Equations not solved correctly.
```

When applying the given solution back into the system of equations, I should expect to receive zeros (or nearly zero). This would confirm that the computed solution solves the given set of equations. I tried checking with this method for both the system of 3 equations and the system of 6 equations, but only the system of 3 equations is solved correctly with this check. What can I do to solve the system of 6 nonlinear equations?

Answer (score 0):

Your system is inconsistent and your initial guess is off. Try adding fourth equation to the first system of three equations:

```
F[0] = 20 * x1 + x2**2  # "first" equation
F[1] = x2 - x1  # "second" (=> x1 == x2)
F[2] = x3 + 5 - x1*x2  # "third"
F[3] = x3 + x2  # "fourth" equation (=> x3 == -x2)
```

First, let's solve first three equations. From the second equation it follows that `x1` is equal to `x2`. Therefore the first equation can be re-written as:

```
F[0] = 20 * x1 + x1**2
```

which leads to `x1 = -20` (and `x2 = -20`). Using this in the third equation leads to `x3 = 395`. Try to modify initial conditions for the first system to `uInitial = np.array([-30, -30, 1])` - you should get the correct answer.

Now, let's solve all four equations. The third equation, using the fact that `x2 == x1`, can be re-written as:

```
F[2] = x3 + 5 - x1**2
```

From the fourth equation it follows that `x3 == -x2` (and so `x3 == -x1` as well). Therefore, this equation can be rewritten as `x3 + 5 - x3**2 == 0` => `x3 = 0.5 +(-) sqrt(21)/2` which is different from `395` that we got above using first three equations.

This shows that you have an inconsistent system of equations which has no solution.